# How to route to dynamic URL in React based on user imput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I am on my URL `localhost:3000/contracts/members` I see something like this:
[image]

QUESTION: How do I make it when I click on 1 of the rows like the 3rd one with Member ID 3564 I am taken to the URL `localhost:3000/contracts/contract?id=3564`?

My Component class code that shows the table above looks like:

```
const SearchBarAndResults = React.createClass({
  render() {
    // other stuff...
              <Tbody> 
                {_.map(memberContractsOnDisplay, (contract) => (
                  <Tr key={contract.member_id} 
                    onClick={this.handleClickedRow.bind(this, contract)}>
                    <Td>{contract.member_id}</Td>
                    <Td>{contract.name}</Td>
                    <Td>{contract.pricing_version}</Td>
                    <Td>{contract.seller_type}</Td>
                    <Td>{contract.selling_enabled}</Td>
                    <Td><BillablePopUp passedProp_is_billable={contract.
                      is_billable}/></Td>
                  </Tr>
                ))}
              </Tbody>
  },
    handleClickedRow(contract) {
    let newURL = '/contracts/contract?id='.concat(contract.member_id);
    browserHistory.push(newURL); // <=== This is changing the URL but isn't loading it
    store.dispatch(getClickedOneLinkedRowAction(contract));
  }
});
```

and my `routes.jsx` looks like:

```
export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <Route path='members' onEnter={onEnterMemberContracts} component={
            MemberContracts} /> 
        // What do I do here to load the Contract component everytime a user
        // hits /contract?id=3564 or a different id?
        <Route path='contract' component={Contract} />
    </Route>
);
```

Comment: did you try dispatching the browserHistory.push?

Comment: how do you dispatch it? `store.dispatch(what here?)`

Comment: `store.dispatch(browserHistory.push(newURL));`

Comment: Do you need to fetch data based off of that id?

Comment: no I already have the data

Comment: are you using redux ? flux?

Comment: redux. If I call store.dispatch(browserHistory.push(newURL)); don't I need to add an case to my reducer function to deal with it?

Comment: not necessarily, (you don't have to capture a dispatch with a constant every time, I dont do that for route updates) that dispatch will cause your reducers to run and then selectors. so assuming you are trying to select the data correctly off of the query then that should do it :)

Comment: Let me know what happens when you do that and I can try and help with the next part. Not sure what you want to do with it visually/data wise.. but you will need to pass down as a prop the selected id after grabbing it from the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110324/discussion-between-q-liu-and-john-ruddell).